Edge case where upon automatic page refresh after deleting saves list, listing in left col still shows that list
Repro steps:

Save some post "A" to a new list "foo"
Save another post "B" and click "manage" (leave the dialog open)
In another tab, go to saves page, open "foo", click "edit", click "delete"
Observe that after the automatic page refresh, "foo" still appears in the left column
Observe that attempting to save post "B" to list "foo" succeeds and says the post is saved to "foo"
Refresh the saves tab
Observe that "foo" no longer appears in the left column
Observe that post "B" is in the "For Later" list

Yes, I am <adjective I can't find> enough to report this edge case that probably no one will ever encounter in regular site usage.
